# How do you convert a string into an array in Ruby on Rails without adding quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I created an array of locations from an API. Now I turn the list into a string so that I can change some things like so:

```
<% @location = @location.to_s.gsub('&', 'and ').gsub('"', '').gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '') %>
 <% @location = @location.split(',') %>
```

when I push the location into the google map (which needs an array), i run into problems because the location.split adds quotes so the actual text has the phrase  &quot around each entry. How can I get these to not be generated when I re-create the array with the split method? The underlying issue is unexpected token &.

Thanks

Comment: Can you illustrate the output you want compared to what you get. Is mashing around strings really the best approach?

Comment: this is probably due to XSS protection. try `<%== @loaction %>`  or `<%= @loaction.html_safe %>` as output. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss)

Comment: Thanks guys, I have tried "raw" and "==" and they end up giving results that aren't useful but what I would  need to do under this strategy. I am now trying to use AJAX to solve the problem